# Exporting an array of custom objects into Access table

Tags: ms-access, excel, vba

I have a timesheet system in excel with 3 rows (standard time, overtime, double time) for each of our (100+) employees, and one column for each cost code on the site. This ends up being a giant matrix, most of which is empty. My solution is to basically create an employee datatype which stores the employee information and hours for a single cost code.

```
   Public Type Employee
     Name As String
     Trade(1 To 3) As String
     EmpNum As Long
     Comment As String
     AddOns(1 To 3) As Single
     Allowance(1 To 3) As Single
     Contract As Long
     CostCode As Long
     STHours As Single
     OTHours As Single
     DTHours As Single
     WorkDate As Date
   End Type
```

I can process the spreadsheet and organize the information in excel as an array of employee-type objects, but I'm not familiar with how to export this into Access, and most questions relate to exporting from excel cells to Access. I can obviously put these objects into cells on another worksheet and do it that way, but it seems like there should be a better way.

Currently my best guess is something like this:

[Insert data form Excel to Access 2010 using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14396627/insert-data-form-excel-to-access-2010-using-vba)

but then I'd be making 100+ updates to the table for each export.

Is there an efficient way to create a table object in VBA, populate it with the array information, and then append it to the end of my table in Access in a single update?

Thanks.

-Sean

Comment: I think that what I'm looking for is to open a recordset in the same format as my access table, populate that recordset with my object array, and then append that recordset with the access table. Is that feasible, or is there an easier way to do that?

Comment: If you are worried about performance, DON'T. For 100 records, it will be done before you can even blink an eye.

Comment: Haha, thanks for that. I'm not really worried about performance, but I'm still curious about learning good coding. I guess for now I'll just use the "inefficient" way.

Comment: One thing that I always try to remind myself most of the time that I am not smarter than the person that designed the software.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create a table link in Access.  Table links look like tables in the rest of Access, but the data is stored externally.  The data could be inside another Access database, or inside a SQL Server database, or what have you.

In particular,  the data can be in an Excel spreadsheet.  Define a table in Excel that contains the data in the format that's right for your Access application.  Then build a table link in Access that links back to the table you defined in Excel.

When you update the Excel table,  the updated results will automatically appear the next time you reference the table link in Access.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The only issue with this is that each day will create a new set of data. I don't want to replace the existing Access table with the excel data ... I want to append it to the data. Eventually, I'll have 500 days worth of timesheet data in this table, but each day I will only be exporting data from the current day. Does this make sense?

Comment: You have two options.  Append the new data to the existing data in excel.  This probably will become unwieldy before you get to 500 days of data.  The other option is to use the table link to link to the new data, and use an update query in Access to append the new data to the existing data, stored in another Access table.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the help from everyone ... I just wanted to share what I came up with for a solution. I ended up building a function to insert one object into the database ... copied and modified from the interwebs. Code below, cheers!

```
Public Function InsertTimeRecord(EmpData As Employee) As Boolean

Dim SaveTime As Date
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

'//Database Location
Const DB_LOCATION = "C:\access\KMP Tracker.mdb"

'//If errors occur the function will exit with a return value of false (insertion failed)
On Error GoTo ErrHandler:

'//Table has a datecreated/datemodified timestamp for each record
SaveTime = Now

'//Open Database
If db Is Nothing Then
   Set db = DAO.Workspaces(0).OpenDatabase("C:\access\KMP Tracker.mdb") 'Removed DB_LOCATION
End If

'//Open Table
If rs Is Nothing Then
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Timesheet Data", dbOpenDynaset)
End If

'//Create a new record
With rs
    .AddNew
    ![EmpName] = EmpData.Name
    ![Trade1] = EmpData.Trade(1)
    ![Trade2] = EmpData.Trade(2)
    ![Trade3] = EmpData.Trade(3)
    ![EmpNum] = EmpData.EmpNum
    ![Comment] = EmpData.Comment
    ![AddOns1] = EmpData.AddOns(1)
    ![AddOns2] = EmpData.AddOns(2)
    ![AddOns3] = EmpData.AddOns(3)
    ![Allowance1] = EmpData.Allowance(1)
    ![Allowance2] = EmpData.Allowance(2)
    ![Allowance3] = EmpData.Allowance(3)
    ![Contract] = EmpData.Contract
    ![CostCode] = EmpData.CostCode
    ![STHours] = EmpData.STHours
    ![OTHours] = EmpData.OTHours
    ![DTHours] = EmpData.DTHours
    ![WorkDate] = EmpData.WorkDate
    ![DateSubmitted] = SaveTime

    '//Insert Record into Database
    .Update
    InsertMachineHoursRecord = True '//SUCCESSFUL INSERTION
End With

'//Note that we use recordset in this example, but equally effective
'//  is to create an update query command text and simply run the update query:
'//  (INSERT INTO Table (Field1, Field2) VALUES (Value1, Value2);

'//Make sure we have closed the database
My_Exit:
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
db.Close
Set db = Nothing
Exit Function

ErrHandler:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume My_Exit
End Function
```