# Access VBA Find Records using Search Critera in Recordset

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, vba

I have an Access database connected to excel. I need to find records using Search criteria in recordset from Excel

1. Table name in MS Access is `MyTable` with more than 10 columns with data
2. User enters string data in Excel cell, let us assume  `Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1)`
3. My need is, macro has to loop through  any matching string in column7 and column 10  and copy corresponding recordset in three columns (column1, column7 and column 10) into Worksheets("ALL").Cells(3, 1)…Cells(3,3), etc
4. Data in column7 and column 10 will have more than 500 character text in one record cell. Search string may present in more than one record cell; hence output will be found in more than one recordset.

Do we have any other option with instr function along with a SQL query?

```
strSQL = "SELECT Qn_No, Categories, Page_Text FROM  MyTable  WHERE Categories = '" & str1 & "' or “&Page_Text &"
```

Any help would be much appreciated. My thanks in advance.

Comment: u really need better phrasing. It's not very clear what u need.

Comment: @Kelaref thanks for looking into this, I need to search through records in one table in access and bring output in excel. If user enter text as "Money Market" , macro should fetch output of record set wherever it sees "Money Market" in two specific column of one table data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.
Remember to enter the path to your access file.

```
Sub test()

Dim p As String 'path of access file
Dim dbConn As Object, dbData As Object
Dim ws As Worksheet 'worksheet where results will be pasted
Dim s As String 'text searched
Dim sql As String 'select statement
Dim cs As String 'connection string
Dim v As Variant 'stores query result


s = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1)
Set ws = Worksheets("ALL")

sql = "SELECT Qn_No, Categories, Page_Text " & _
    "FROM  MyTable  " & _
    "WHERE Categories = '" & s & "' OR " & _
        "Page_Text = '" & s & "'"

'################################
cs = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=" & p & ";Persist Security Info=False;"

Set dbConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set dbData = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
dbConn.ConnectionString = cs
dbConn.Open
With dbData
    .ActiveConnection = dbConn
    .Source = sql
    .LockType = 1
    .CursorType = 2
    .Open
End With
'Connection to access ready
'###############################

On Error GoTo NoRecords 'no records
v = dbData.GetRows
On Error GoTo 0

'v is zero based array, an records are transposed
'Handle it as you wish

ws.Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(v, 1) + 1, UBound(v, 2) + 1).Value = v
GoTo Quitter

'######################
NoRecords:
  MsgBox ("No Records Found")
Quitter:
  dbData.Close
  Set dbData = Nothing
  dbConn.Close
  Set dbConn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you brother!. I will use this and let you know the status.

Comment: Note that ADO can cause memory leaks, consider DAO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14396627/insert-data-form-excel-to-access-2010-using-vba/14397496#14397496 In addition, DAO is much faster and native to Access.

Comment: @Kelaref What could be the syntax error of this ? sql = "SELECT C_WI, C_Inquiry, C_TD_Response " & _
    "FROM  T_TT " & _
    "WHERE [C_Inquiry] LIKE '%" & strSearch & " %' OR " & _
        "[C_TD_Response] LIKE '%" & strSearch & " %'"

Comment: Any chance strSearch contains special characters?

Comment: @kelaref Thank you Kelaref!. I corrected the syntax error and able to get my desired out put. Again thank you for all the help!